# Knockout mvc dynamic text to the parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout-mvc

I have a question about a parameter Knockout mvc http://knockoutmvc.com/

```
input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" value=""

@ko.Html.Button("Go", "Increment", "ParametersToServer", new { value = "txtSearch???" })
```

I want to use dynamic text to the parameter

Plz...

Comment: what you mean by dynamic text, means from model?

Comment: ex) button or submit... Search by Target